# View logs in GCP Cloud Function Error: The caller does not have permission

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have the Cloud Functions Developer Role, and I created a new Cloud Function. I put in a few print statements for debugging, however, when I run my function and try to view the logs I get the following message:

> Error: The caller does not have permission

[image]

Comment: You have one of the [Cloud Functions predefined roles](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/iam/roles) but you also need one of the [Cloud Logging predefined roles](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/access-control#permissions_and_roles)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @DazWilkin, you should also have [Cloud Logging predefined roles](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/access-control#permissions_and_roles) to view logs.

Follow these steps to add predefined roles:

1. In the Cloud Console, select [IAM & Admin](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam?).
2. Navigate to your preferred Principal and click the *Edit principal* (pencil icon).
3. *****+** ADD ANOTHER ROLE***, then select a role.
4. Navigate to ***Logging*** > ***"Logs Viewer"*** (or prefer Role).
5. Click ***"SAVE"***.

These steps can help you configure/add roles to your principal in order to view your logs.